# Qt C++ Get data from a selected row of a table view

Tags: c++, qt

I have a table view populated with data of `Vehicle` objects stored in a `QList<Vehicle> cars`; On this `cars` list i have to make some actions: search, add, edit, delete; After every action of search, i store the founded objects in another list to populate the table view only with this objects, keeping the original list intact. The original list gets modified only on add, edit or delete. Here comes the problem: i search for an object that i want to edit, it is shown in the table view, i select it and press the edit button; i am using `QModelIndexList` to get the index of the row. The index of the row will give me the position from the "founded" list, and i need to modify the object in the original list. Below is my implementation.
Is there any other way to this thing without the temporary list? How can i modify the original object using Iterator, instead that for loop?

```
void MainWindow::on_actionEdit_triggered()
{
QMessageBox msgBox;
QModelIndexList id = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
if(id.isEmpty()){
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Message");
    msgBox.setText("Please select a row");
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox.exec();

} else{
    int row = id.at(0).row();
    QUuid carId = temp.at(row).getVehicleID(); // temp -> the "the founded" list 
    for(int i = 0; i < cars.size(); i++){
        Vehicle& current = cars[i];
        Vehicle& currentTemp = temp[row];
        if(carId == current.getVehicleID() && carId == currentTemp.getVehicleID()){
            addDialog = new AddEditDialog(this);
            addDialog->loadVehicleToEdit(current);
            addDialog->exec();
            if(addDialog->getIsEdited()){
                current = addDialog->getVehicleToAdd();
                currentTemp = addDialog->getVehicleToAdd();
                currentTemp.setVehicleId(carId);
                current.setVehicleId(carId);
            }
        }
    }
}

//create header
createHeader(model);
//set data to the table view
populate(temp);
```

}

Comment: The loop can be replaced by using std::find_if. Either with classic function object or lambda (C++11). Temp list is another  story which I do not immediately understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you use proxy model and you need to call mapToSource?